# How to check permissions for a user or group in Sharepoint 2010 using C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

In Sharepoint 2010, clicking `"Site Actions"--> "Site Permission" --> "Check Permissin"`, you can get permission by user. How can I do the same thing using sharepoint API in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SPWeb.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getusereffectivepermissioninfo.aspx)

> Gets the effective permissions that the specified user has and the role assignments related to this user within this scope.

Answer (score 3):

The method "GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo" server users only.
If the permissions need to find a group, just do this:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPGroup spGroupItem = web.Groups["GroupName"];
        SPRoleAssignment oRoleAssignment = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(spGroupItem);

        foreach (SPRoleDefinition inRole in oRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
        {
            //inRole.id //inRole.Name
            //1073741829 //limited access
        }
    }
}
```